# Text classification + NLP + Python : Warning: The least populated class in y has only 23 members, which is too few

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

I am working on a text classification problem for which I am using 30 fold cross validation. Before starting experiment I made sure that each class had at least 30 members. Then I did necessary text processing and split my dataset into test and train sets.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data['event_name_description'], data['category_id'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Test set consists of 20% of total data. Now when I run my model for training, I get this warning:

```
/home/hp/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:553: Warning: The least populated class in y has only 23 members, which is too few. The minimum number of labels for any class cannot be less than n_folds=30.
```

Apparently, it seems **after splitting my data into test set and train set**, I have at least one class in my **train set** which has as few as 23 members. Am I correct?

Comment: to clear confusion, you said at the start of the question that you had at least 30 samples for all labels. But towards the end of the question you said that at least 1 label had 23 samples. I think the error will be resolved if all of your classes have 30 samples each.

Comment: @Regressor : I made some goof up. Please read my question again. I edited.